# Bind form from request and logged in user

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm here again with a question about Play2.0 :-).

I have a model called `Task`. This task contains a field called `createdBy`. This field must be populated with the **logged in user.**

My field declaration looks like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@Constraints.Required
public User createdBy;
```

I render a form where the logged in user can enter a *description* and a *priority* from a drop down box. When the form is submited I call my `save()` method. In the save method I have this code:

```
Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class).bindFromRequest();

if (taskForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(views.html.tasks.taskCreate.render(taskForm));
}
taskForm.get().save();
```

Obviously the `Task` is never saved because the field `createdBy` does not contain any (valid) user. The only reference to the user is that I save his unique **CODE** and not the primary key in the session.

I can only get it work when I remove the *Required* constraint and postfill the user to the saved task. There must be a better way to bind the form and user together, right?

Answer (score 2):

What Play2.0 wants you to do is making a distinction between your 'database model' and your 'form bean'. I also think there should be a better solution. But on the other hand, it is pretty clean. So what you should do is:

1. Create a 'form bean' called `TaskForm`, for example. This class only contains the fields that are displayed in your form, with the right annotations and validation.
2. Create a `toTask(User user)` method in your `TaskForm` which returns a `Task`.
3. Change the code in your controller to:

   ```
   Form<TaskForm> taskForm = form(TaskForm.class).bindFromRequest();

   if (taskForm.hasErrors()) {
     return badRequest(views.html.tasks.taskCreate.render(taskForm));
   }
   taskForm.get().toTask(user).save();
   ```
4. Keep the annotations/validation in your 'model class' `Task`, but look at them as database validation, not form validation.

Edit:

- Some extra explanation: I had several discussions about this validation/binding problems on the Play group: [discussion1](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/MSx5rGW6Z9g/discussion), [discussion2](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/Ll7SYwabI4o/discussion). The idea of the Play Developers, as I understand it, is to use the Form class for binding/validation. This Form class wraps an existing class. I think there is nothing wrong with their idea that this wrapped class is a 1-to-1 representation of a form. Only the problem is, the Scala language makes this a lot easier then the Java language. in Java you have to create lots of 'form representation classes' where in Scala you can use things like 'mapping' and 'case classes' ([see ScalaForms](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms)). So I totally agree with your points in the comments that it is probably not worthy to write a new 'form bean' for one different property, and you would rather have your validation in one place. But that is how it is designed, yet. I hope that either they change the API by themself, or someone else takes a good look at it and submits a pull request. But right now, this is how the framework wants you to do your binding/validation.
- Example:

  ```
  public class Task extends Model {

      @Constraints.Required
      public String description;

      @Constraints.Required
      public Integer priority;

      @ManyToOne
      @Constraints.Required
      public User createdBy;

      public Task() {
      }

      public Task(final TaskForm taskForm, final Long userCode) {
          description = taskForm.description;
          userCode = taskForm.userCode;
          createdBy = User.findByCode(userCode);
      }

  }

  public class TaskForm {

      @Constraints.Required
      public String description;

      @Constraints.Required
      public Integer priority;

      public toTask(final Long userCode) {
          return new Task(this, userCode);
      }

  }

  public class Tasks extends Controller {

      public static Result save() {
          Form<TaskForm> taskForm = form(TaskForm.class).bindFromRequest();

          if (taskForm.hasErrors()) {
              return badRequest(views.html.tasks.taskCreate.render(taskForm));
          }
          taskForm.get().toTask(session("userCode")).save();
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: Li-o I'm not sure if writing 'form beans' for binding one property is worth of it, however it would be great if you could write a sample code for points 1,2 and 4 as it can be used in other cases to demonstrate more sophisticated scenarios. I would personally vote it up!

Comment: Li-o, I have thought about writing a POJO for the form, but I'm not sure if this is maintainable since I would love to have the constraints on one class instead of everywhere throughout the app. But +1 for suggestion of biesor :-)

Comment: @biesior and adis: I've edited my answer to answer your questions. It would be to long for a comment ;).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the required annotation from your model and bind new task in two steps:

```
Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class).bindFromRequest();

if (taskForm.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest(views.html.tasks.taskCreate.render(taskForm));
}

Task newTask = taskForm.get();
newTask.createdBy = someObjectOfUserModel;
newTask.save();

return ok("New user added");
```